# Connection string in ADO. Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

What code should I write in my web.config for the connection string for DB connectivity with an ado.net component?

Comment: perhaps if you tell us what RDBMS you are connecting to, then someone could help you. Try connectionstrings in google/bing ....

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/08/26/Using-connection-strings-from-web.config-in-ASP.NET-v2.0.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
[www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You can get a complete listing here

[**ADO Connection String Samples**](http://www.codemaker.co.uk/it/tips/ado_conn.htm#SQLClientManagedProvider)